# Help on understanding how to express sets and their relations graphically

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

> Let $A=\{0,1\}, B=\{a,b,c\}, R=id_A, S=\{(a,b),(a,c) \}\cup id_B$
>
> Express graphically the following:
>
> $(A,R)+(B,S)\\ 
> (B,S)+(A,R)\\
> (A,R)\times(B,S)\\
> (B,S)\times(A,R)$

I'm not sure how to express these sets and I couldn't find any examples online. Are $R,S$ relations here ? So how would a union with id work ?

This is what I came up with:

[image]

If it's right then, I think that $(B,S)+(A,R)$ is basically flipped image of $(A,R)+(B,S)$, and $(A,R)\times(B,S)$ would be like combining the first two.

Comment: $R$ and $S$ seem to be relations, but I haven't seen the $(A,R)+(B,S)$ or $(A,R)\times (B,S)$ notations before and couldn't find an online reference. They look like disjoint union and cartesian product, but I'd feel better if you could provide a definition in the question.

Comment: @askyle thanks, that's the problem, we never defined these and the examples we saw aren't very useful to me at least because they're not similar at all.

Comment: Is this from a course? Sounds weird that they'd ask you about concepts they haven't defined. I'll go with the definitions that look more probable to me at the moment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right about $R$ and $S$ being relations (defined as sets of ordered pairs). $id_B$ there is the *identity relation* on $B$, namely the set $\{(a,a), (b,b), (c,c)\}$; so the "union with id" part is just saying that these pairs are also part of $S$. In other words, $S$ is *reflexive* (every element of $B$ is related to itself under $S$).

To express them graphically, you'd draw a dot for each element in the set, and then an arrow for each pair of related elements (so if $(a,b)$ is in $S$, you'd draw an arrow from $a$ to $b$). If an element relates to itself, you'd draw a little loop.

The $+$ probably represents the *[disjoint union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_union)* operation. On sets, $A+B$ can be seen as having a copy of $A$ on the left and a copy of $B$ on the right, with no relation between them. Formally, in this case:

$$\begin{align}
A+B &= \{x_\triangleleft\mid x\in A\} \cup \{y_\triangleright\mid y\in B\} \\
    &= \{0_\triangleleft, 1_\triangleleft, a_\triangleright, b_\triangleright, c_\triangleright \}
\end{align}$$

where $\triangleleft$ and $\triangleright$ are arbitrary tags. Usually they're implemented as $x_\triangleleft=(0,x)$ and $x_\triangleright=(1,x)$, but that isn't too important and would have been confusing in this case. Since $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, I could have gotten away with just taking the union, but if $A$ and $B$ have common elements, we need some way of telling the left copy from the right copy. Graphically, you're literally drawing two copies, so there's no need to add the tags.

This extends naturally for relations: $(A,R)+(B,S)$ will be $R$ on the left copy of $A$ and $S$ on the right copy of $B$. Formally:
$$\begin{align}
(A,R)+(B,S) &= \{(x_\triangleleft, x'_\triangleleft)\mid (x, x')\in R\} \cup \{(y_\triangleright, y'_\triangleright)\mid (y, y')\in S\} \\
            &= \{(0_\triangleleft, 0_\triangleleft), \dots \}
\end{align}$$

Try spelling out the full list of ordered pairs for that definition, and drawing it (one dot for each tagged element, one arrow for each ordered pair of tagged elements). You should end up with a drawing of $R$ and a drawing of $S$, side by side.

As for $\times$: On sets it represents the Cartesian product operation (the set of ordered pairs). On relations, I **think** it represents the [*direct product*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_graphs) operation. Like for disjoint union, we need to make a pair of relations work on a new, common base set—this time, a set of ordered pairs. Again, there's a natural way to do that:

$$\begin{align}
(A,R)\times (B, S) &= \{(\langle x, y\rangle, \langle x', y'\rangle)\mid (x,x')\in R \land (y,y')\in S\} \\
                   &= \{(\langle 0, a\rangle, \langle 0, a\rangle), \dots\}
\end{align}$$

(I'm using angle brackets to make the inner and outer parentheses easier to tell apart). In other words, two pairs are related if and only if their respective components are related. Again, try spelling out the whole list and drawing it. You end up with a sort of network, with copies of $R$ weaved with copies of $S$ (see the image in the Wikipedia link for an example), though your example will be a lot simpler since $R$ is just the identity relation.

(Note: the Wikipedia link talks about the tensor product on graphs, but that's pretty much the same thing.)

Comment: @kuhaku If the answer helped, an update to the question with the drawings you came up with could be a nice touch :)